# AxWindowsMediaPlayer play a song

Tags: exception, audio, visual-studio-2012, axwindowsmediaplayer

Can I please have some help to play a audio file with the AxWindowsMediaPlayer.

I am using Visual Basic.net 2012 Ultimate.

Here is my code:

```
Imports AxWMPLib

Public Class Form1

Public WithEvents MediaPlayerObject As AxWindowsMediaPlayer = New AxWindowsMediaPlayer

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    MediaPlayerObject = New AxWindowsMediaPlayer
    MediaPlayerObject.Ctlenabled = True
    MediaPlayerObject.URL = "C:\Users\Simon\Music\Music\CanLucidDream\108761__soundbytez__birds-late-morning.wav"
    MediaPlayerObject.Ctlcontrols.play()
End Sub
```

End Class

I get the following error when trying to access any of the objects properties or methods:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.InvalidActiveXStateException' occurred in AxInterop.WMPLib.dll

Answer (score 0):

You need to pay attention that

```
-MediaPlayerObject.URL = "C:\Users\Simon\Music\Music\CanLucidDream\108761__soundbytez__birds-late-morning.wav"-
```

should be like this;

```
MediaPlayerObject.URL = "C:\\\Users\\\Simon\\\Music\\\Music\\\CanLucidDream\\\108761__soundbytez__birds-late-morning.wav"
```

or like this;

```
MediaPlayerObject.URL = @"C:\Users\Simon\Music\Music\CanLucidDream\108761__soundbytez__birds-late-morning.wav"
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to call BeginInit() and EndInit() before using any properties or methods.

```
MediaPlayerObject.BeginInit()
MediaPlayerObject.EndInit()
MediaPlayerObject.CtlEnabled = True
```